# Fresh ubuntu 20.04 install but unclaimed nvidia graphic card?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 20.04, graphics

Whenever I run the command `sudo lshw -C display` I receive:

```
*-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: UHD Graphics 620
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 07
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:129 memory:dd000000-ddffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: 3D controller
       product: GP108M [GeForce MX150]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:de000000-deffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:df000000-df07ffff
```

The command `sudo ubuntu-drivers devices` gives

```
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001D10sv00001028sd00000828bc03sc02i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GP108M [GeForce MX150]
driver   : nvidia-driver-450-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-440-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-418-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-450 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-455 - third-party free recommended
driver   : nvidia-driver-435 - distro non-free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

And lastly, `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` returns

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nvidia-driver-455 : Depends: libnvidia-gl-455 (= 455.28-0ubuntu0~0.20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-extra-455 (= 455.28-0ubuntu0~0.20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-decode-455 (= 455.28-0ubuntu0~0.20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-encode-455 (= 455.28-0ubuntu0~0.20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: nvidia-utils-455 (= 455.28-0ubuntu0~0.20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-455 (= 455.28-0ubuntu0~0.20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-cfg1-455 (= 455.28-0ubuntu0~0.20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-ifr1-455 (= 455.28-0ubuntu0~0.20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-fbc1-455 (= 455.28-0ubuntu0~0.20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: libnvidia-decode-455:i386 (= 455.28-0ubuntu0~0.20.04.1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-encode-455:i386 (= 455.28-0ubuntu0~0.20.04.1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-ifr1-455:i386 (= 455.28-0ubuntu0~0.20.04.1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-fbc1-455:i386 (= 455.28-0ubuntu0~0.20.04.1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-gl-455:i386 (= 455.28-0ubuntu0~0.20.04.1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

As you can see, I do have GeForce MX150 but for some reason I don't know, I cannot use it nor download its drives. Could you give me some advice on how to proceed?

Note: I have already disabled safe boot through `sudo mokutil --disable-validation`.

Comment: Have you made sure you have the latest info on what's available for your repos?  `sudo apt update` BEFORE running your attempt to install

Comment: Running `sudo apt update` tells me to run `apt -a list --upgradable`, which in turn says that nvidia-driver-440 is upgradable. But when I try to upgrade (full or dist-upgrade) , I receive `The following packages have been kept back:
  nvidia-driver-440`.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me after some trial and error. Once you have disabled safe boot using `sudo mokutil --disable-validation` try the following.

1. Remove all your existing drivers first
2. Install the driver but make sure to use autoinstall to allow the recommended driver to be installed `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`
3. During the end of the installation process, **you should see a screen asking you to set up a password** that would allow third party drivers to be used during bootup. Set this password and finish the installation.
4. Reboot and **during the boot process**, choose "ENROLL MOK" and select the key. You will be asked for the password in previous step here. Enter it. (This step could look different depending on your bootloader)

The above steps helped me change my GPU driver from unclaimed to normal (see image). Additionally, you will also see the driver in the configuration which was earlier missing. Hope that helps.

Some of the steps of my solution were taken from here but please don't follow their order - https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-nvidia-drivers-ubuntu

[image]